# Sudo environment variable

Tags: c, environment-variables, sudo, getenv

I want to create an environment variable and set it in `sudo`, I mean, I want it to be in `sudo printenv` but I just can put it in `printenv`.

I am making a program and I need to run the program with `sudo` and inside I use `getenv()`, but running the program with `sudo` it does not work properly.

Does anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it right before executing the command. For example:

```
sudo A=B printenv
```

Comment: if you write `sudo printenv` after that, the variable isnt there, I think like that you are not creating it

Comment: @difegui: It sets it only for that single `printenv` command. Is that not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: It only lasts for the extent of the command run within that one `sudo`. There isn't a persistent `sudo` environment. If you want that, invoke a privileged shell.

Comment: `sudo env A=B printenv` should also work unless `env` doesn't exist as a standalone program such as `/usr/bin/env`

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Yes, that will also work, but it's no better than `sudo A=B printenv`. (Note that `sudo` handles the `A=B` syntax itself; it doesn't pass it off to the shell.)

Comment: Thank you, but no, it isnt enough because when I run the program, the variable needs to be in `printenv`, maybe it has to be persistent there, because I need to get that variable inside my program, and just with that it is still not working..

Comment: @difegui If you call `printf("%s\n", getenv("A"));` in your program, you'll see that it prints `BCD` when run as `sudo A=BCD printenv`. If it doesn't, either you're not running the correct `printenv` program or you forgot to recompile and install the newly compiled `printenv`.

Comment: if I do that, the printf just show (null) . What do you mean with ¨recompile and install the newly compiled `printenv` ¨ maybe it could be that.

Comment: @difegui Instead of running `printenv` run your program that same way: `sudo A=BCD yourexecutable`